# Caching text file contents in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, caching, sinatra

I'm new to Sinatra and programming for the web, so some of the terminology used may not be quite right. Anyway...

I have an app that reads a .txt line by line into an array and then when you load the index.html.erb it randomly displays one of the lines. I put the contents in a text file instead of directly into an array so that if I need to add more data it's easier to update then adding to the array directly and redeploying the app. My concern is if it's recreating the array and rereading the file every time you load the page. I don't know exactly how that kind of thing works server side, or how to check it. The code that creates the array reads:

```
before do
  @ways ||= ['']
  if @ways[1].nil?
    File.open('ways.txt', 'r').each_line { |line| @ways << line }
  end
end
```

And then my route:

```
get '/' do
  @way = @ways.sample

  erb :index
end
```

Is there a way to make sure this is as efficient as possible? Or should it be done some other way entirely? According to the Chrome Dev tools, it transfers ~ 800b per page load.

Comment: Hint: to get random array element use `@ways.sample`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have written here will indeed read the file into an array on each request.

*Tip: you can make it shorter and faster with `@ways = File.readlines('ways.txt')`*

If you wanted to cache this array, you could do so as a constant at app startup, e.g.:

```
WAYS = File.readlines('ways.txt').map(&:chomp)
get "/" do
  @way = WAYS.sample
  erb :index
end
```

However, with this you would need to quit and restart your server if you edited the text file. If you wanted to avoid that, you could check the modification time of the file in your `before` action and only update the array (`replace` it) if the contents had changed.

*If you need help with this last suggestion, let me know and I can edit to suit.*

---

**Edit**: Here's one way to use a constant to save the data and reload only when the file changes:

```
WAYS = { file:'ways.txt', all:[] }
before do
  if WAYS[:updated] != (mtime=File.mtime(WAYS[:file]))
    WAYS[:all].replace File.readlines(WAYS[:file]).map(&:chomp)
    WAYS[:updated] = mtime
  end
end
get "/" do
  @way = WAYS[:all].sample
  erb :index
end
```

This is a little bit aggressive—checking the file modification time on every request—but the performance should be fine for all but the heaviest load or slowest disk.

An alternative solution would be to kick off a thread to force-check/update the array every few minutes, e.g.

```
require 'sinatra'

WAYS = { file:'ways.txt', all:[] }
Thread.new do
  loop do
    if WAYS[:updated] != (mtime= File.mtime(WAYS[:file]))
      WAYS[:all].replace File.readlines(WAYS[:file]).map(&:chomp)
      WAYS[:updated] = mtime
    end
    sleep 5 # seconds
  end
end

get '/' do
  WAYS[:all].sample
end
```

Comment: I understand what you're getting at, but if you could flesh it out a little I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This is fantastic! You've given me a lot to read up on. Thanks so much!

Comment: Would it be practical to use a much longer sleep time, like 86400 (1 day) or is sleep meant to be used with shorter times? I assume under either method the Thread lives forever since the loop runs forever, so the amount of time sleeping shouldn't use up any more or less processing power (except the fewer runs would be less processor intensive)?

Comment: It's totally practical. I have a web app that uses threads to (a) sleep for 5 minutes at a time (between sending queued emails) and (b) sleeps for 24 hours at a time (updating a denormalized stats table in the DB with a once-per-day snapshot).

Comment: Hmm, this actually isn't working for me. For one thing, the array isn't getting populated, and for another the WAYS variable needs to be accessible from the views, but I should be able to fix that by just making it an instance variable.

Comment: @thekungfuman No, an instance variable is specific to a request; you need a data structure that persists across requests

Comment: Oops! I had a typo. Fixed. I've edited the answer to include a complete standalone example that works for me locally (tested).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11716/discussion-between-thekungfuman-and-phrogz)

Comment: Never used the chat function before. It's kind of neat. Although that link is impossible to see for _continue this in chat_ on my monitor.

Comment: Got it working! The last piece of the puzzle was 
@way_num = WAYS[:all].index(@way)